Azure Dev Ops Pipeline Triggers Not Working
I have an ADO pipeline, pipeline1 which needs to trigger pipeline2 if it is successfully completed.
Pipeline1 has an 'orchestrator' YAML file which calls several other templates. Pipeline2 has the exact same logic.
The difference is that I have added a resource block into pipeline2's orchestrator yml file which should influence a run of the subsequent yml templates if pipeline1 is successful. To be clear, this resource block is not within a template.
This is the logic:
trigger: none
pr:none

resources:
   pipelines:
   - pipeline: P1
     source: pipeline1 
     trigger: true

The reason why I would like to use this pipeline trigger in my YAML file Vs Build Completion trigger in the UI is because this allows me to eventually specify branches and stages that must be successful in order to execute pipeline2.
I actually managed to get a successful pipeline2 run with this logic. I then went on to add stages and branch specifiers, which didn't work, and when I returned to the original code it no longer works. I feel I have made sure to replicate the original conditions but perhaps I'm overlooking something.
Other bits:

Pipeline1 and 2 are on the same branch in the same repo.

They are in the same project in my ADO board.

I have configured the default branch for both pipelines to be the same branch.

Although I have added trigger: none and pr: none to disable CI and Pull Request triggers, I have tested enabling or disabling these triggers in the UI, to no avail.


